# Not receiving confirmation email for product orders.

Tags: php, smtp, opencart

I'm using Opencart Version 2.1.0.1

I'm receiving all the emails except for order confirmation email.

The admin and the customer are not receiving the order confirmation email. Other than this all other services which require email are working. I'm using zohomail in smtp.

I want the client and the admin to receive the confirmation email soon as the client's order's a product.

Anyone know how to solve this ?

Comment: was there any modifications done to the core system?

Comment: I"m not sure about it. Is there any way to find it out ?

Comment: check the error log to see if any errors are showing up, if not then you have to go through the code and see if there are any changes manually

Comment: no errors in the error log. No changes in the files relating to checkout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on **New Order Alert Mail** from admin panel store setting. Update your setting from here

**Setting > Edit Setting> Option Tab > New Order Alert Mail**

Comment: That is already turned on. Yet it the confirmation isn't being sent.